# Compressing(Zipping) VS2010 Solutions - issue when opening

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to compress a Visual Studio 2010 Solution into zipped folder, so I can transfer it over email.

I have done this before, but for some reason, when I just tried it, and tested reopening the zipped solution, I get the following

> *C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp3_WcfServiceConsole.zip\WcfServiceConsole\WcfServiceConsole\WcfServiceConsole.csproj:
>   error  : Unable to read the project file 'WcfServiceConsole.csproj'.
>
> *C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp3_WcfServiceConsole.zip\WcfServiceConsole\WcfServiceConsole\WcfServiceConsole.csproj:
>
>   The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path  'C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp3_WcfServiceConsole.zip\WcfServiceConsole\WcfServiceConsole\WcfServiceConsole.csproj'.*

I can't figure out why it would be doing this?

Is there another way I can zip up the solution correctly so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: I've never had a problem. I've used both windows built in zip tool and winzip.

Make sure you unzipped it. Save the file and unzip in to a known location, not local/temp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty nice that Windows Explorer lets you look into a .zip file as though it is a directory.  That's where the buck stops though, there is no .zip archive support built into Visual Studio.

You have to unzip the archive first.

To avoid a mistake like that in the future, switch Explorer to Programmer Mode.  Start + Run, explorer.exe.  Organize, Folder and Search options, View tab.  Untick the "Hide extensions for known file types" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unzip the zip before trying to open it. It looks like you're just double-clicking the zip in Windows Explorer, then trying to open the solution file directly from the zip archive. That is, the path:

```
C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp3_WcfServiceConsole_**.zip**\WcfServiceConsole\WcfServiceConsole\WcfServiceConsole.csproj
```

appears to be a path within a zip file. Visual Studio can't work with this until you unzip it.